# How to obtain list of count() results using JpaRepository @Query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, nativequery, spring-repositories

I'm building REST API connected to ORACLE 11G DB. API sends data to Android client using JSON. To get data I'm using JpaRepository, and `@Query` annotations.

I want to provide data for charts: number of contracts in years.

I have native SQL query:

```sql
select aa.ROK, count(aa.NUMER_UMOWY) 
from (select distinct NUMER_UMOWY, ROK from AGR_EFEKTY) aa 
group by aa.ROK order by aa.ROK
```

Result of query using SQL Developer look like this:

[image]

I tried to get result using native query:

[image]

But result is always like this:

[image]

or error depending what I try.

Is it possible to obtain list of `count()` results using `@Query`?

If not, what should I use?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Add the @Query code.. not as img

Comment: These results could have been also posted as text

Comment: Add the `NumberOfContracts` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think What you are trying to use here is spring data projection. 
As mentioned in the reference doc:

> Spring Data query methods usually return one or multiple instances of
>   the aggregate root managed by the repository. However, it might
>   sometimes be desirable to create projections based on certain
>   attributes of those types. Spring Data allows modeling dedicated
>   return types, to more selectively retrieve partial views of the
>   managed aggregates.

and particularly closed projection where all accessor methods match the target attributes. In your case the count is not an attribute of your aggregate.
To perform what you want you can use constructor as follow :

```
class ContractsDto{


  private String rok;
  private int count;

  public ContractsDto(String rok, int count) {
    this.rok=rok;
    this.count =count;
  }
  // getters
}
```

The query will be:

```
@Query(value = "select new ContractsDto(aa.rok , /*count */) from fromClause")
 List<ContractsDto> getContractsPerYear();
```